# Restful Web Services [PUT Request]

Tags: python, html, flask

I am looking to tackle a question to use PUT request to update a resource

This is the request:
METHOD PUT => http://localhost:8081/user/int:id

BODY => {“email”: “abc@bmail.com”}

Req.json.matching
Use for loop
i is the index

and response should be:

a)If user with matching id exists in the list:

http status code 200
{“message”: “User with  has been successfully updated!”}

b)If user with matching id does not exists in the list:
http status code 404

{“message”: “User with  does not exist!”}

Below is the code I have tried after researching on my own from the web:

```
from flask import Flask,jsonify,request
app = Flask (__name__)

users=[{"userid":1,"username":"John","email":"john@gmailer.com","role":"member","password":"abc123"}]

@app.route('/users/<int:id>',methods=["PUT"])
def updateUser(userid):

    id = [user for user in users if (users['userid'] == userid)]

    if 'userid' in request.json:
        id[0]['userid'] = request.json['userid']

    if 'email' in request.json:
        id[0]['email'] = request.json['email']

    return jsonify({'user':id[0]})



if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True) #server will auto-restart when we save our changes to the code
```

I am not able to get the result wanted. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are quite a few mismatches in your requirements and what the code actually does. I came up with a code snippet that I think matches your requirements pretty well, but I also still have some open points. I'll list them at the end of the answer, in case I made the wrong assumption.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, abort

app = Flask(__name__)

users = [{"userid": 1, "username": "John", "email": "john@gmailer.com", "role": "member", "password": "abc123"}]


@app.route('/users/<int:userid>', methods=["PUT"])
def updateUser(userid):
    for user in users:
        if user["userid"] == userid:
            if 'userid' in request.json:
                user['userid'] = request.json['userid']
            if 'email' in request.json:
                user['email'] = request.json['email']
            return jsonify({'user': user})
    abort(404)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

There were a few odd things within your code:

- You should never shadow built-in names: The name `id` is a python build-in. This can in some cases cause unforeseen things.
- There was a typo in the list comprehension of the `id` variable: It said `users['userid']`, but it should be `user['userid']` (note the plural "s" in your code).
- The method expects a parameter `userid`, but the route defines the param as `id` (`'/users/<int:id>'`). It should also be `'/users/<int:userid>'`.
- You don't need the list comprehension just loop over the list and as soon as you find your user you do your task and return.
- Your code had no logic for the error case, when not finding the user. See in my example code how I loop over the users and when I exit the loop, meaning I didn't find the user, I call `abort`. It cancels the request and returns an error code (in this case 404).
- By default flask uses port 5000, so your put request to port 8081 would not work, but I guess that is due to copying the code into stack overflow.
- Do you really want to allow updating the userid? This was not mentioned in the question and usually in backend code such a thing is not a good idea, since the id is your unique identifier. If it were changed and a user chagned it to an already existing one your code may result in strange behaviours.
- In your question you say you want to return `200 {“message”: “User with has been successfully updated!”}` in case of success, but your code returns the updated user. I wasn't sure which option to take here, so I kept the returning of the user.

This is quite a lot of information, but I wanted to provide all my findings from your code. Maybe it helps you and you could learn something from it :) If it's still not working as supposed, leave a comment below and/or update your question.